# Computing the sum of the series with term$\frac{3^n-e}{\delta+3^n-e}0.5^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is there a way to compute the sum of the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{3^n-e}{\delta+3^n-e}0.5^n$, where $\delta, e \in \mathbb{R}^+$?

I can give more context on the problem at hand, if needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there no other conditions on the constants apart from the one's you've given?

Comment: I'm considering the case where δ=1 and e=4

Comment: @MattS no other conditions

Comment: Yeah, in that case there's no way to evaluate it. It seems that it could sum to various things.

Comment: @MattS I'm looking for an expression in terms of delta and e. It's natural that the sum will depend on the values of delta and e considered.

Answer (score 0):

$\delta =1$ and $e=4$ give $\delta +3^n-e=0$ and division through zero at $n=1$, so the series is undefined then.

with $3^n=1/x$ we have a power series
$$
\frac{3^n-e}{3^n-e+\delta}
=
1 +\delta \sum_{i\ge 1} (-)^i (\delta -e)^{i-1}x^i
.
$$
Naively interchanging the two series (not sure whether this is allowed here)
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{3^n-e}{3^n-e+\delta}\frac{1}{2^n}
=
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{2^n} +\delta \sum_{i\ge 1} (-)^i (\delta -e)^{i-1}\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^i}{2^n}
$$
These are geometric series with known summation:
$$
=
1 +\delta \sum_{i\ge 1} (-)^i (\delta -e)^{i-1}\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{2^n3^{in}}
$$
$$
=
1 +\delta \sum_{i\ge 1} (-)^i (\delta -e)^{i-1}\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^i-1}
$$
$$
=
1 +\frac{\delta}{\delta -e} \sum_{i\ge 1} (-)^i \frac{(\delta -e)^i}{2\cdot 3^i-1}
$$
$$
=
1 +\frac{\delta}{2(\delta -e)} \sum_{i\ge 1} \frac{(e-\delta)^i}{3^i-1/2}
$$
and $\epsilon \equiv (e-\delta)/3$
$$
=
1 +\frac{\delta}{2(\delta -e)} \sum_{i\ge 1} \frac{\epsilon ^i}{1-(1/2)3^{-i}}
$$
$$
=
1 +\frac{\delta}{2(\delta -e)} \sum_{i\ge 1} \epsilon ^i\sum_{j\ge 0}\frac{1}{(2\cdot 3^i)^j}
$$
$$
=
1 +\frac{\delta}{2(\delta -e)} \sum_{i\ge 1} \sum_{j\ge 0}\frac{1}{2^j} \frac{\epsilon^i}{(3^j)^i}
$$
$$
=
1 +\frac{\delta}{2(\delta -e)} \sum_{j\ge 0}\frac{1}{2^j} \frac{\epsilon/3^j}{1-\epsilon/3^j}
$$
$$
=
1 +\frac{\delta}{2(\delta -e)} \sum_{j\ge 0}\frac{\epsilon/6^j}{1-\epsilon/3^j}
$$
and here I am basically stuck.