# Determine the maximum parameter of a series such that its limit is positive

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

**Problem**

Consider the following series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{3^{n}-e}{\delta+(3^{n}-e)}\right]\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$

where $\delta >0$ is a fixed constant, and $e>0$ can be considered a parameter for this series. It can be shown by ratio test that this series converges for any $e$. However, one is interested to know the $\text{sup}$ of $e$ such that the above series has a positive limit. How should such $e$ be determined?

**Related approaches and questions**

Actually there has already been a similar question on this series, see:

1. [Computing the sum of the series with term$\frac{3^n-e}{\delta+3^n-e}0.5^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865402/computing-the-sum-of-the-series-with-term%24%5Cfrac%7B3%5En-e%7D%7B%5Cdelta%2B3%5En-e%7D0.5%5En%24)

Comment: What's $\delta$?

Comment: It can be any positive integer. The series should be dependent on both $e$ and $\delta$, but ratio test shows their choices do not matter as long as $3^n - e \neq -\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

At least to me, this is not a simple problem.

Changing notations (I do not like to see $e$ is a formula when it is not Euler number), I considered
$$f(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(3^n-a) }{b+(3^n-a) }\frac 1{2^n}$$ and looked at the contour plots and 3D plots of $f(a,b)$ computed numerically; this is quiate revealing ant I suggest you try it.

The only point which seems to be possible to calculate is
$$f(a,a)=1-\frac a 5$$ which is positive if $a<5$

Comment: Thank you. In general, what sorts of algorithm can be used to numerically determine the value of this series given any $a,b$ such that $a>0, b>0$ and $a$ is such that no denominator in each term of the series vanishes? 

I was also considering the partial sum of $f(a,b)$, and since the partial sum is a decreasing function of $a$, one may be able to find the $a_N$ at which the partial sum is equal to 0 and then that $a_N$ would be the desired sup for a given $N$?

Comment: @Hephaes. I still have no idea but I am still working the general problem. If anything comes to my old poor brain, I shall post.